# Is there a way to get FFPLAY read from stdin in Matlab using .NET?

Tags: .net, matlab, ffmpeg

I'm trying to read raw h.264 stream from FFMPEG output, process it in Matlab, send it to FFPLAY and display it from there. I use .NET libraries in Matlab, and I am able to read the stream from FFMPEG stdout into Matlab. However, I could not manage to send the processed data to FFPLAY's stdin. What am I doing wrong?

I set up an ffmpeg process to read from its output using System.Diagnostics of .NET in Matlab. Similarly, I set up another process for ffplay. I redirected stdout of ffmpeg and stdin of ffplay. Then, I read lines from ffmpeg and wrote those to ffplay. However, ffplay did not display anything.

Also, when I try to write to a file from ffmpeg stdout and send ffplay that file, it doesn't work either. This makes me suspect data drops from ffmpeg stdout, but don't know how to verify this.

```
pFFMPEG = System.Diagnostics.Process();
pFFMPEG.StartInfo = System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo;
pFFMPEG.StartInfo.FileName = 'ffmpeg.exe';
pFFMPEG.StartInfo.Arguments = '-y -nostdin -f dshow -framerate 5 -i video="Logitech Webcam C925e" -vf scale=160:120 -vcodec h264 -an -map 0:v -f nut -';
pFFMPEG.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
pFFMPEG.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
pFFMPEG.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = false;
pFFMPEG.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
pFFMPEG.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

pFFPLAY = System.Diagnostics.Process();
pFFPLAY.StartInfo = System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo;
pFFPLAY.StartInfo.FileName = 'ffplay.exe';
pFFPLAY.StartInfo.Arguments = '-i - -autoexit';
pFFPLAY.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
pFFPLAY.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
pFFPLAY.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = false;
pFFPLAY.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = false;
pFFPLAY.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;

t = zeros(150,1);
ctr = 0;
L = 0;
arr = zeros(10000, 1);

pFFMPEG.Start();
ffmpegOut = pFFMPEG.StandardOutput;

temp = ffmpegOut.ReadLine();
temp_arr = uint8(char(temp));
%here, process temp_arr and convert back to char arr temp%
pFFPLAY.Start();
ffplayIn = pFFPLAY.StandardInput;
ffplayIn.WriteLine(temp);

while ~(isempty(temp)) && ctr < 150 && L < length(arr)
    L_end = L+temp.Length;
    arr(L+1:L_end) = temp_arr;
    temp = ffmpegOut.ReadLine();
    L = L_end;
    temp_arr = uint8(char(temp));
    %here, process temp_arr and convert back to char arr temp %
    ffplayIn.WriteLine(temp);
    ctr = ctr + 1;
end
```

When I look into the Matlab workspace, I seem to get the output of ffmpeg into Matlab in arr, although I am not sure if there are any drops. 
When I try to send the data to ffplay, nothing happens. I can see ffplay process is running, but no video window shows up.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What does  the ffplay log say?

Comment: @Gyan It displays configuration and writes a few lines of `nan    :  0.000 fd=   0 aq=    0KB vq=    0KB sq=    0B f=0/0`.
After that, it either stops without saying anything, or sometimes says "Nut stream header 0 checksum mismatch" and quits.

Comment: My guess at this point is some packets drop somewhere and I suspect this happens at the output of ffmpeg when I try to read it into Matlab. Since there are missing packets, ffplay either never receives a 'start' command, or sometimes detects a partial header and misses the rest and hence the checksum mismatch. Is there a way to detect such drops?